# spl_autoload_register not working in included files

Tags: php, autoload

I'm using [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register) in order to load classes.

I have an `index.php` file that includes an `init.php` file. The `spl_autoload_register` function is called in the `init.php` file.

In the `index.php` file, it works properly: I can create classes and stuff, their names are resolved.

But later on, in the `index.php`, I include another file, `work.php` to do some specific task.

Oddly, in the `work.php`, the class I'm using are not found.

If I call the `spl_autoload_register` once again in `work.php`, the class can then be resolved.

The really odd thing about it is that this behavior is not consistent: On my test server, I don't have to duplicate the `spl_autoload_register` call, but on my production server, it's compulsory.

Am I missing some options in the `php.ini`?

**Edit/Updated:** Here is the content on the `init.php` file, just in case:

```
<?php
function my_autoload($class){
    include 'class/' . $class . '.class.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoload');
?>
```

And my index.php :

```
<?php
require_once 'include/init.php';

$barcode = new Barcode();
// here is a bunch of test and stuff
include 'work.php';
?>
```

And my work.php :

```
<?php
$myObj = new Barcode();
// more useles stuff
?>
```

The barcode is created flawlessly in the index.php code part, but fails in the work.php part...

Comment: Show the code of your autoload function?

Comment: You also need to share the `index.php` file and the `work.php` file. Also this calls for basic debugging first. For example instead of using `include` you should use `require` to make your program fail when a file can not be resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your `include_path` setting if it contains the local directory.

Generally it is not a good idea to use relative paths. It's easy to create an absolute path that's relative to your init.php file like this:

```
function my_autoload($class){
    include __DIR__.'/class/' . $class . '.class.php';
}
```

This code assumes that your init.php file is in the same folder as the 'class' folder.

Also, instead of potentially creating errors with blindly including files that may or may not exist in the given path, check the existence of the file before including it:

```
function my_autoload($class){
    $file = __DIR__.'/class/' . $class . '.class.php';
    if(file_exists($file)) {
       include $file;
    }
}
```

Please note that `__DIR__` is a PHP 5.3 feature which is not be available on  hosts with PHP 5.2. You can substitute it with `dirname(__FILE__)`

Also, please note that on Linux the file is searched for in a **case-sensitive** manner, whole on most Mac OS X install, the file is looked for case-insensitively. If you instantiate class `MyClass` Linux will look for `MyClass.class.php` while Mac OS X would also load the class if it was in file called `myclass.class.php`, `Myclass.class.php`, etc.

Comment: Sadly, the server is under php 5.2. Anyway, the odd thing is the inconsistency. Why would it work locally (with a url like localhost/test/index.php) and not remotly (with a url like www.mywebsite/test/index.php) ?

Comment: Have you checked the `include_path` settings on both servers? My guess is that the remote server does not have "." in its include path. PHP 5.2 is no problem, just use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead of `__DIR__`

Comment: Well, actually, both include_path include the "." but thanks to your answer and the use of dirname(__FILE__), I managed to solve the problem. I still don't understand what happen though...

Comment: I spoke too fast... still same problem. Include ignored by the second include file.

Comment: Added more info on case sensitivity to my answer. Maybe that's the reason for the difference.

Comment: I updated my post, to give more details. Maybe it'll bring some light to my problem ? Thanks for your answers anyway :-)

Answer (score 5):

Well, actually, I'm a dumbass. The problem was not with include path etc, but with an apache configuration : MultiViews.

My website has a single access point : index.php. And I redirect everything on it using url rewriting. But thanks to multiviews options, url rewriting wasn't working properly if the url was of the same name than the file.

My directory contains index.php, and work.php.

My script with rewrite was like that : if you hit www.mywebsite.com/work, you go on index.php with param url=work.
index.php initialises everything, then includes work.php

But thanks to MultiViews options, if I was hitting www.mywebsite.com/work, it would search for file, find a work.php, and call it directly. Meaning : no init, meaning : no spl_autoload_register.

Thanks for your answers, and sorry.